# FIWARE Context Broker or Custom API Gateway

Tags: fiware, api-gateway, fiware-orion, maximo, fiware-cygnus

I hope I'll find a reply to a bad (for me) question for which i don't find an answer at the moment.

I have to synchronize information between an enterprise asset management software, based on  IBM Maximo, and an external data lake. In order to achieve this target I can develop a custom API gateway useful to receive any update/insert of data in Maximo. Or, I could use FIWARE Context Broker developing a custom data model for my asset management entities (and relationship) in order to store data having benefits in terms of NGSI protocol.

Both FIWARE Context Broker or API Gateway can be extended in order to provide public services to an IoT platform or other systems of third parties. So, why shall I use FIWARE Context Broker or a custom API Gateway? What's your advice and considerations?

I put below an example of a generic architecture
[image]

Thank you so much for any reply.

Comment: Could you edit your question post to add a picture with the architecture alternatives you are proposing, please?

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for programmers to ask and answer questions. We like questions with a [example]. Open opinion questions like this are not well received..

Comment: I suggest you review [ask].